# How to change permission of a vmdk disk image mounted on Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, permissions, vmware, mount

I created a disk image from a Linux/Ubuntu physical machine using `dd` and converted it to `vmdk` using `qemu`.

Now on Ubuntu (running in VMWare Fusion/Mac) I can inspect all files from that drive once it is mounted.

But all files/folders belong to `root` or `1001`.

How can I change ownership of the mounted vmdk drive to my current Ubuntu user `mike`?

Currently I'm unable to make any changes to files in this mount due permissions errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to convert the *.iso* file into a *.vmdk*. You can just place the *iso* image into the virtual cd reader, and boot off that. Then you can install it.

This solution, which is simpler than the one you adopted, might have the advantage, at this point, to circumvent the issue with file permissions. Have you tried to loop mount the iso, and see whether the file permissions have been altered? If not, this is the simplest way out for you.

Comment: marius originally it was a `img` file. If I convert to `iso`, would I mount it within Ubuntu (not VMWare)? What app do you recommend for conversion/mounting?

Comment: @torr Do not convert it just yet: in this page, https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=95326, the post by Vain teaches you how to mount a partition inside the img file. Do it this way, then check that permissions have been preserved. To convert to iso, then use *ccd2iso*